# Responses to emails sent from the API not threaded

Tags: gmail-api

I noticed that when I send messages from the gmail API and then get an email response to them, the response is never threaded with the original message. Repro steps:

1. On gmail.com, create a new email draft to someone. Don't send it.
2. Go to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list and log in at the bottom. Enter 'me' for userId and click Execute to get the ID for your draft.
3. Go to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/send, log in at the bottom, enter 'me' for userId and fill in the ID from step 2. Click Execute to send the draft.
4. Have the other person respond to your email.

On gmail.com, the person's response is not threaded with the original email that was sent. However, this works just fine if you send from the gmail UI instead of the API. In examining the headers, the only difference is that the API adds a second 'Received' header. I'm not sure if this is the cause of gmail not threading.

Has anyone else seen this? What is the gmail.com UI different from the API when sending a draft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug.  Barring issues rolling out the fix, should be resolved by next Weds, July 9th.

Comment: Is there a link to an issue or bug fix for this so that we can track it.